# Error al correr python code

Tags: python, vscode, terminal

soy nuevo en esto de programar en python y tengo este problema cuando quiero correr mi codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que entrar a la carpeta ```c to f``` que tienes y allí ejecutar tu app

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi ganes tu primera medalla! Y también lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: O darle al triangulito verde que ves arriba a la derecha

Comment: Hola @christian, cómo accedo manualmente a la carpeta?

Comment: @Waldo Sobrino con ```cd nombre de la carpeta``` puedes tener un error al hacer eso si la carpeta cuenta con espacios en su nombre, trata de renombrar la carpeta

Answer (score 2):

Tenes que estar dentro de la carpeta donde está guardado el archivo `app.py`.
Para eso, si usas la terminal, debes entrar al directorio correspondiente, en este caso, debes escribir `cd c to f`, y luego ejecutar el archivo. Si usas VSCode, no hace falta el `python app.py`, con escribir `app.py` ya está bien.

Un tip para que sea más cómodo acceder a los directorios: los nombres de las carpetas o archivos, intenta que sean una sola palabra, o si son más de una, usa guión bajo, `c_to_f`.